# Trying to understand the concepts behind JavaScript event handlers

Tags: javascript, dom-events

As a beginner in JavaScript, one is slightly confused with the

```
addEventListener()
```

function, as opposed to the use of

```
variable.onclick
```

Here is the code that I am testing it with:

```
    /*
     * A simple function to swap the text of two elements        
     */
     function swapFunction(){
        var siteTitle   = document.getElementById("site_title");
        var siteText    = document.getElementById("site_text");
        
        var temp            = siteTitle.innerHTML;
        siteTitle.innerHTML = siteText.innerHTML;           
        siteText.innerHTML  = temp;
        return false;
     } 
    
     /*
      * A function to handle the page load
      */
     function fullyLoaded(){            
        var testEvent =       document.getElementById("test_click");            
        
        /* 
         * Why does the line that has been commented out not work
         * Yet the line beneath it does?
         */
        
        //testEvent.addEventListener("click", swapFunction(), false);
        testEvent.onclick = swapFunction;
    }
            
    window.onload = fullyLoaded;
```

Html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>This is a test application</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="site_title">Welcome To My Site</h1>
<p id="site_text">This is a test site that I am practising on</p>
<a id="test_click" href="#">test click</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help to explain the concept of event handlers and `addEventListener()` or `attachEvent()` in IE.

Comment: Much like the jQuery implementation of events and event handling like click() for example, onclick is simply an alias, or shortcut for what is actually happening behind the scenes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
testEvent.addEventListener("click", swapFunction(), false);
```

to

```
testEvent.addEventListener("click", swapFunction, false);
```

Because when you write braces () after the function name, it executes immediately, but you wanna pass the function as an argument. When you use braces, you do not pass the function, you pass its return value.

Good luck in JS learning!

Answer (score 1):

The `onclick` method is based on the older API, which was replaced by DOM 2 Events.  This is mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) on the always-excellent MDN:

> addEventListener() was introduced with the DOM 2 Events specification. Before then, event listeners were registered as follows:

```
// Pass a function reference — do not add '()' after it, which would call the function!
el.onclick = modifyText;
```

---

The commented line below does not work, because you're invoking `swapFunction` immediately (ie, you're sending the *result* of `swapFunction`, rather than the function itself).  This is the correct syntax:

```
testEvent.addEventListener("click", swapFunction, false);
```

// "swapFunction", not "swapFunction()"